# How to predict a label in MultiClass classification model in pytorch?

Tags: conv-neural-network, pytorch, multilabel-classification, multiclass-classification

I am currently working on my  mini-project, where I predict movie genres based on their posters. So in the dataset that I have, each movie can have from 1 to 3 genres, therefore each instance can belong to multiple classes. I have total of 15 classes(15 genres). So now I am facing with the problem of how to do predictions  using pytorch for this particular problem.

In pytorch CIFAR-tutorial, where each instance can have only one class ( for example, if image is a car it should belong to class of cars) and there are 10 classes in total. So in this case, model prediction is defined in the following way(copying code snippet from pytorch website):

```
import torch.optim as optim

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)

for epoch in range(2):  # loop over the dataset multiple times

running_loss = 0.0
for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
    # get the inputs
    inputs, labels = data

    # zero the parameter gradients
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    # forward + backward + optimize
    outputs = net(inputs)
    loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    # print statistics
    running_loss += loss.item()
    if i % 2000 == 1999:    # print every 2000 mini-batches
        print('[%d, %5d] loss: %.3f' %
              (epoch + 1, i + 1, running_loss / 2000))
        running_loss = 0.0
```

print('Finished Training')

Question 1(for training part). What could you suggest to use  as an activation function. I was thinking about BCEWithLogitsLoss() but I am not sure how good it will be.

and then the accuracy of prediction for testset is defined in the following way:
for the entire network:

```
correct = 0
total = 0
with torch.no_grad():
    for data in testloader:
        images, labels = data
        outputs = net(images)
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
        total += labels.size(0)
        correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()

print('Accuracy of the network on the 10000 test images: %d %%' % (
    100 * correct / total))
```

and for each class:

```
class_correct = list(0. for i in range(10))
class_total = list(0. for i in range(10))
with torch.no_grad():
    for data in testloader:
        images, labels = data
        outputs = net(images)
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs, 1)
        c = (predicted == labels).squeeze()
        for i in range(4):
            label = labels[i]
            class_correct[label] += c[i].item()
            class_total[label] += 1


for i in range(10):
    print('Accuracy of %5s : %2d %%' % (
        classes[i], 100 * class_correct[i] / class_total[i]))
```

where the output is as follows:

```
Accuracy of plane : 36 % 
Accuracy of   car : 40 % 
Accuracy of  bird : 30 % 
Accuracy of   cat : 19 % 
Accuracy of  deer : 28 % 
Accuracy of   dog : 17 % 
Accuracy of  frog : 34 % 
Accuracy of horse : 43 % 
Accuracy of  ship : 57 % 
Accuracy of truck : 35 %
```

Now here is question 2:
How can I determine the accuracy so it would look in the following way:

For example:

```
The Matrix (1999)                ['Action: 91%', 'Drama: 25%', 'Adventure: 13%']
The Others (2001)                ['Drama: 76%', 'Horror: 65%', 'Action: 41%']
Alien: Resurrection (1997)       ['Horror: 67%', 'Action: 64%', 'Drama: 43%']
The Martian (2015)               ['Drama: 95%', 'Adventure: 81%']
```

Considering that every movie does not always have 3 genres, sometimes is 2 and sometimes is 1. So  as I see it, I should find 3 maximum values, 2 maximum values or 1 maximum value of my output list , which is list of 15 genres so, for example, if

my predicted genres are [Movie, Adventure] then

some_kind_of_function(outputs) should give me output of

[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0] ,

which I can compare afterwards with ground_truth.
 I don't think torchmax will work in this case, cause it gives only one max value from [weigts array], so

What's the best way to implement it?

Thank you in advance, appreciate any help or suggestion:)

Comment: I'm not sure about the loss function for your mini project, but I suggest you to understand CIFAR-10 little more. Think like this, the CIFAR-10 CNN is computing probabilities for input image to be one of 10 classes. In the end, you just print the max number out of 10 and hope it is true. So, in your case, you will have 15 classes (corresponding to 15 genre). After successful training, your model will generate an array of 15 probabilities for each input poster. You can pick top 3 to show best 3 genre or 5 for top 5. Other way is to set a cut off probability say 0.6 & show all classes > 0.6.

Comment: Hi @MohanaRao, thank you for your explanation, I see how probability is being computed, however since my labels don't always have one value, it is a tensor that can have up to 3 elements, I cannot train my data properly, because my loss is not computed correctly and I get an error like ValueError: Target size (torch.Size([4, 3])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([4, 15]))

Answer (score 1):

1. You're right, you're looking to perform binary classification (is poster X a drama movie or not? Is it an action movie or not?) for each poster-genre pair. `BinaryCrossEntropy(WithLogits)` is the way to go.
2. Regarding the best metric to evaluate your resulting algorithm, it's up to you, what are *you* looking for. But you may want to investigate ideas like [precision and recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall) or [f1 score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score). *Personally*, I would probably pick the top 3 for each genre (since that's at max number of genres assigned to each poster) and look if the ones to be expected show up with high probability and if the unexpected ones (in case of a movie with 2 "ground truth" genres) show at the last places, with significantly less probability assigned.

Comment: Hi @Jatentaki, thanks for answering. I tried nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss(), however in this case I have a following error ValueError: Target size (torch.Size([4, 3])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([4, 15])), since I have 15 classes as my final output of fully connected layer, but each label contains 3 elements and my mini-batch is 4. How do I proceed then? Is it a good idea to remove last two elements from each label and then do the loss? Will it be accurate? Or is it better to go through each of the element of label then when I do loss = criterion(outputs, labels)?

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow. If you have 15 labels your network also needs to output 15 logits - one for each of the classes. If you want to tell your network "look, there can be at most 3 labels, so please make use of that info and do not even bother outputting more than 3 nonzero values", that's difficult to do. And, in the end, against the probabilistic approach - you know it can be at most three, but there can be more than three which are plausible considering the poster alone.

Comment: What I say is is to train network, I should have #of input instances be equal to # of my labels. My input is an array of 30000 images, and my labels are 30000 lists, where each list is 1,2 or 3 labels. Since I can't make a proper batch and tensor out of my lists, I think , I have to flatten the list of lists, but then I have around 80000 labels. So, my question is, can I cut it to 30000 so it would match my size of the tensor of my input . Is it a good idea? Or is there a better solution to it ?

Comment: I feel like in this case, I don't even need my labels, I can just uniformly distribute 30000 numbers in a range of [0:15]

Comment: Why can't you make a tensor out of your lists? You need to assign each unique label a number, like 0 - drama, 1 - adventure, etc and turn the lists into one-hot encoding vectors, exactly as you described in your original post. Then each of your posters is associated with a vector of exactly 15 numbers and you can easily build a tensor of shape `[n_posters, 15]`. I'm sorry, but I don't understand your point with uniformly distributing 30000 numbers

Comment: I can and I already vectorized my labels, so they are in the following format:  tensor([[ 2., 10., 5.],
[ 2., 5., 1.],
[14., 2., 3.],
[ 1., 0., 0.]]) ,and minibatch is 4. But now, If I try to use CrossEntropyLoss and train it this way, pytorch throws errors like batch don't match or dimensions won't or number of element in batch don't match. I feel like this happens cause my labels format is list of lists and each element of batch is a list. I tried to avioid this problem by flattening list and cut my data to match # of  input elements. So now my batch looks like  - tensor([ 9, 10,  3,  9])

Comment: I am planning to train in this way, and when it comes to validation part, I will take p the top 3 values out of my array of weights and see if they match the ground truth labels. Is that efficient or am I missing something?